# How to get current logged in user's star rating in SharePoint 2013

Tags: client-object-model, rating

Currently,  I am developing a custom web part to show star rating for documents, everything is done.

However,when user hover on the star I want a tooltip message("Your current rating is 1..."), similar to what we have in libraries(or what the sharepoint by default provides in libraries).

So can I get the user specific rating depending upon the logged in user using code(.net or CSOM anything will work)?

Answer (score 2):

How to get Social Rating for List Item via CSOM (JacaScript)

```
function getItemRating(listTitle,itemId, success,error)
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var item = list.getItemById(itemId);

    context.load(item);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        function() {
            var ratingEntry = {};
            ratingEntry.AverageRating = item.get_item('AverageRating');
            ratingEntry.RatingCount = item.get_item('RatingCount');
            ratingEntry.Ratings = item.get_item('Ratings');
            success(ratingEntry);           
        },
        function(sender,args)
        {
            error(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}

//Usage
getItemRating('Documents',5,function(ratingEntry){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ratingEntry)); 
},
function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Please refer [How To Use CSOM with Ratings in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/07/08/how-to-use-csom-with-ratings-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) for a more details.

---

Another option would be to utilize [SocialDataService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice%28v=office.15%29.aspx) Web Service using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SocialDataService), the following operations are available:

- [GetRatingAverageOnUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingaverageonurl.aspx)
- [GetRatingOfUserOnUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingofuseronurl.aspx)
- [GetRatingOnUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingonurl.aspx)
- [GetRatingsOfUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingsofuser.aspx)
- [GetRatingsOnUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.getratingsonurl.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods on SocialRatingManager, one to retrieve all rating given the URL and another to retrieve all rating given by a user. Documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialratingmanager.getratings(v=office.15).aspx

See the code sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407954.aspx)

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("SharePoint site URL"))
{
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
UserProfileManager myUserProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
UserProfile myUserProfile = myUserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(false);
SocialRatingManager mySocialRatingManager = new SocialRatingManager(context);
SocialRating[] ratings = mySocialRatingManager.GetRatings(myUserProfile);
Console.WriteLine("Ratings for user:");
foreach (SocialRating rating in ratings)
{
   Console.WriteLine(rating.Url + ": " + rating.Rating);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...Can this be done using ECMA script COM